# Integration of angular based web application with Freshdesk

Tags: oauth, integration, freshdesk

WE have our current Angular based SPA application which we would like to integrate within Freshdesk ticketing system.  It would be like a IFRAME on ticket page which will render our application and agent who is working on ticket can use our application in IFRAME.

I installed Freshdesk CLI and tried to create sample freshdesk app and it did show up in ticket window, but now when I tried to create another app using "fdk create", it does not even go to next step.

My questions:

1. can you direct me to correct documentation which will guide me step by step how I can integrate my SPA application in freshdesk using IFRAME apporach?
2. can you share some examples?
3. How can I direct freshdesk logged in agent to our SPA url within IFRAME, where our application will authorize freshdesk logged in agent to view our app?

Thanks in advance.

I have sample custom app that I am able to render in ticket view page.  This way I am able to render my application home page, but how do I get authorization from Freshdesk and render my app in iframe?

Once I created the application using "fdk create" , now I am not able to create the another app using the same command.

Answer (score 1):

- Freshdesk now supports a newer [App location](https://developers.freshdesk.com/v2/docs/app-locations/) called `full_page_app` that can be accessed from global side bar.
- Example: To render an app in iframe, after you create `your_first_app` try adding `<iframe>` tag and embed your website in `template.html`
- You can read [this](https://medium.com/freshworks-developer-blog/building-a-full-page-app-on-freshdesk-5ce17524277f) blog on how to do it.
- Download the code from the sample app [here](https://github.com/freshdesk/marketplace-sample-apps/tree/master/Freshdesk/v2/sample_full_page_app).

Freshworks developer platform now supports OAuth 2.0 capabilities. As soon as you add an `config/oauth_config.json` with respect to [this documentation](https://developers.freshdesk.com/v2/docs/oauth/), the app will be loaded only after OAuth handshake is performed. In either case you can use Basic Auth as well.

You cannot use same `fdk create` command if the directory is not empty. Make sure you create a new folder and navigate there first.